# Why does Chrome show these (rails-jquery) alerts twice but Firefox doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I stop these rails-js-jquery popups from being repeated in Firefox?
They only show once in Chrome... though not in 'Chromium' on my Ubuntu machine.
I checked Chrome and I have no extensions installed.

The javascript gets runs twice so I see 4 messages.
The others parts are working ok (db gets updated, ui span gets updated)

The haml is `app/views/link/index.haml`

```
= link_to 'verify', verify_link_path(:id => link.id, :table_row => index),  
  class: 'verify', remote: true
```

The javascript is `app/views/links/verify_link.js.erb`

```
$("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").text('verified');
alert("message 1");
alert("message 2");
```

The controller is `app/controllers/links_controller.rb`

```
def verify_link
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.verified_date = Time.now
  @link.save!
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
  end 
end
```

The js is verify_link_js.erb:

```
$("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").text('verified');
alert("message 1");
alert("message 2");
```

The network tab only shows the js file once for each verify click.
The pop-ups in Chrome are:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Whereas in Firefox I just get

[image][image]

Comment: Are you _getting_ the script twice, or is it _run_ twice? (check the network)

Comment: Once.  Updated q with more info.

Comment: This is a client-side problem first of all, so show client-side code.

Comment: Anything still containing `<%=…` is not client-side code. And besides that, we still have no information about the surrounding code – like what _triggers_ this script to be requested (seems to happen on each click, but on what and when), etc.

Comment: CBrow it is a rails js erb file which gets compiled into js.  Anyway answer found (below).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to why they were showing twice (though not why *not* in Firefox!) is that my javascript assets file (`app/assets/javascript/application.js`) had the following:

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min
//= require default_on_first_input_field
//= require row_shading
//= require sortable_hook
//= require_tree .
```

This was basically requiring the files twice - individually and then through `require_tree`.

My preferred solution was to remove the individual requires.  It's ok to require everything for this project... and in fact require_tree was doing just that.  So I changed it to just

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Interestingly, this issue had just not shown itself up to now in the existing javascript functions.  They presumably were 'ok' to run twice which makes sense, e.g. "row shading twice" is ok.  So basically this was a remaining 'artififact' of my upgrade to use the asset pipeline from an app that had started at rails 2.3.8 (before it).